# Need my HTML Search Form to search the Options Selected on the Search Form and then show my results?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, search

I have a website with 4 pages: Home Page , Sale Page , Rent Page and Contact Us Page.

On the Home Page is a Search Form that need to Search the Options they select. It is a Property website so if they click on the search button they need to be taken to the Sale Page or Rent Page what they have selected, for instance if they Select For Sale, House, 3 Bedrooms, 2 Bathrooms and then whatever amount on Min Price / Max Price then it needs to go to the Sale Page and retrieve the Houses on the Values they have Selected.

Here is a Image of the Search Form:

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this please?

**Here is the HTML Search Form coding:**

```
<form id="advanced_search" action="search.php" class="clearfix" name="advanced_search" method="post">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<label for="type"><b>Type</b></label>
<select>
  <option value="House">House</option>
  <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
  <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
  <option value="Townhouse">Townhouse</option>
  <option value="Plot">Plot</option>
  <option value="Farm">Farm</option>
</select>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<label for="status"><b>Status</b></label>
<select>
  <option value="For Sale">For Sale</option>
  <option value="For Rent">For Rent</option>
</select>

</div>


<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<label for="bedrooms"><b>Bedrooms</b></label>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<label for="baths"><b>Bathrooms</b></label>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>


</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<label for="min_price"><b>Min Price</b></label>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<label for="max_price"><b>Max Price</b></label>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<button name="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SEARCH PROPERTY</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Here is the PHP Coding that I am struggling with:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$key=$_POST["search"];  //key=pattern to be searched
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM properties WHERE");




while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{




}
}

?>
```

Comment: What are you struggling with, specifically? What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$type = $_POST['type'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$minPrice = $_POST['min_price'];
$maxPrice = $_POST['max_price'];
$bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms'];
$baths = $_POST['baths'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","house");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM properties  WHERE tipo='$type' and baths = '$baths' and bedrooms = '$bedrooms' and status = '$status' and price between '$minPrice' and '$maxPrice'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['type'] . " " . $row['status'];
  echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

I have created a table here and it is working.
Do not forget to change on html code " tag and add on this the property "name"

Comment: are you using the code which i have posted? what php is saying on error?

Comment: please, can you post your whole code? Containing also the sql tables then I can check the same code.

Comment: Do you maybe have skype?

Comment: sure, send to me your skype name.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong, first you didn't named your html form tags, and secondly you didn't use the $key variable in your php code to modify your query. You need learn about basic form interactions. I also strongly suggest you to look into [MVC](http://kohanaframework.org/), having a sql connection just 10 lines above the template code is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this:
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM properties WHERE");

first question, are the options: "max price, type and etc..." on the same table?

you can do something like that:

$type = $_POST['type'];

$status = $_POST['status'];

$minPrice = $_POST['minPrice'];

$maxPrice = $_POST['maxPrice'];

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM properties WHERE type='$type' and status = '$status' and max_price between '$minPrice' and '$maxPrice'");

to the same for another fields, should work

Comment: one more thing, be careful concerning sql injections

Comment: Yes it's on the same table

Comment: O no sorry there are one that is different. on the table I have Price and not min price /max price. Because If I create a property then I only put in one Price. then when they search min and max price they must get the properties between that prices

Comment: I gave to you an example, try please

Comment: Will give it a try just now

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: type, status, bedrooms, bathrooms, min and max price in C:\wamp\www\sa property finder\search.php on line 11

Comment: yes, because you have to put the name on component, for example: <select name="type">, you have the name on label and you're getting data from select, change it... put name in all of them :)

Comment: well, look your html code, you have this for example:
<select>... put in all selects a name.. like this: <select name="type"> if you did not get this, I will post the fix to you

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM properties WHERE

type='$type' and status = '$status' and bedrooms = '$bedrooms' and baths = '$baths' and price = '$minprice' and '$maxprice'");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$type = $_POST['type'];

$status = $_POST['status'];

$bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms'];

$baths = $_POST['baths'];

$minprice = $_POST['minprice'];

$maxprice = $_POST['maxprice'];

Comment: Ok I see sorry now I understand let me do this quickly

Comment: I will test your source code... give me few minutes :)

Comment: Thank you very much Romulos for your help, you see I have a table and inside the table is Price, but that needs to be linked to the min and max price.

Comment: No problem, :) I just posted a new example. Note, it is a simple code, you can make much more better. As i said before be careful with sql injections :) but try to run it

Answer (score 0):

try this in your query:

```
$type = $_POST['$type'];
$status = $_POST['$status'];
$bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms'];
$bathrooms = $_POST['bathrooms'];
$minPrice = $_POST['minPrice'];
$maxPrice = $_POST['maxPrice'];

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM properties WHERE type = '$type' and status = '$status' and bedrooms='$bedrooms' and bathrooms = '$bathrooms' and price between $minPrice and $maxPrice");
```

it will work if your code above your $result is ok

Comment: but will it go to the Sale page or Rent Page when they select it?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: type, status, bedrooms, bathrooms, min and max price in C:\wamp\www\sa property finder\search.php on line 11

Comment: depends of your code... you can do a IF... if type = 'rent' then go to rent page... if type is sale, go to sale page, you can do this using $type variable.